# How to add images to a JFrame project

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

This has been confusing me for quite a long time now. The problem is that I want to display some images in a JFrame. I know how to do that, just use `ImageIcon`. However, it requires a path to the image. So if I compiled the project into a jar and gave it to my friend, the image would not appear because the image file is not on my friend's device!

In Android Studio, the IDE takes care of these stuff. You just need to put the images into the `drawable` folder and it generates the code for you. The same applies to Visual Studio. I just need to "Import" the images.

But I see nothing in Eclipse regarding image resources. How can I add images to the JFrame through an "Image resource" thingy?

Comment: search for questions tagged by java + swing + image + embedded resource, voting to close

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drag and drop your image to your project and in url section type this

```
ImageIcon ic = new ImageIcon(getResource().getClass("Example.jpg")); // image name instead of Example.jpg
```

Comment: What is "url section"? Can you show me a screenshot?

Comment: From url section I mean url of image. From this method you can use image from your project

Comment: when you will make jar file image will be in your project

Comment: Where should I put the image? Is the root folder fine? Or in the package that the class is in?

Comment: @Sweeper: you put it in the jar file at a location relative to the class files, usually in its own folder.

Comment: Just drag your image and drop it in your project src folder